# codeigniter autocomplete with jquery not working ~ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter, autocomplete

I know there are a few questions relating to this on SO but none answer my specific issue.

I have been trying to get an autocomplete input working with [this](http://vortexdev.netii.net/article_16/How_to%3a_Autocomplete_with_CodeIgniter_and_jQuery) tutorial

The page loads correctly without errors however when I insert a letter I receive errors in the developer console:
`GET http://localhost/autocomplete/getResult/ 500 (Internal Server Error)`

the source of the error comes from `jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5`.

Is there a setting in Codeigniter that needs to be changed to allow GET to work or is there a syntax issue with my code:

**Controller**

```
    <?php

class Autocomplete extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('autocomplete_model'); 
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('autocomplete');
    }

    function getResult($title)
    {
        var $result = $this->autocomplete_model->a_method('customerName',$title);
        echo json_encode($result);

    }
}
```

**View**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         test
      </title>
      <link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" media="screen" type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
<body>

   <form>

      <label for="search">Search</label>
      <input type="text" id="search">
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php base_url() ?>" id="hiddenurl">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">

   </form>
<?php echo  base_url(); ?>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 





</body>

</html>
```

**Autocomplete.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        var searched=$('#search').val()
        var fullurl= $('#hiddenurl').val() + 'autocomplete/getResult/' + searched
        $.getJSON(fullurl,function(result){

            var elements = [];
            $.each(result,function(i,val){
                elements.push(val.title)
            })
            $('#search').autocomplete({
                source:elements
            })
        })
    })
})
```

The tutorial uses `jquery-1.6.2.min.js` and `jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js`.

I am using `jquery-1.9.1.min.js` and `jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js`. I assume this wont be the issue as these are later versions of jquery.

My config file has the following settings relating to CSRF:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
```

Any advice is appreciated, sure it is something simple.

**UPDATE**

as per assistance from @undefined, made the following changes to my code:

**Controller**

```
    <?php

class Autocomplete extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('autocomplete_model'); 
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('autocomplete');
    }

    function getResult($title)
    {
        var $result = $this->autocomplete_model->a_method('customerName',$title);
        echo json_encode($result);

    }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
class autocomplete_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function a_method() {
        $query = $this->db->like('CustomerName',$title);
        $query = $this->db->get('customers');
    return $query->result();

    }
}
```

**View - unchanged**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
         test
      </title>
      <link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" media="screen" type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
<body>
   <form>
      <label for="search">Search</label>
      <input type="text" id="search">
      <input type="hidden" value="<?php base_url() ?>" id="hiddenurl">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
   </form>
<?php echo  base_url(); ?>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**autocomplete.js - unchanged**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        var searched=$('#search').val()
        var fullurl= $('#hiddenurl').val() + 'autocomplete/getResult/' + searched
        $.getJSON(fullurl,function(result){

            var elements = [];
            $.each(result,function(i,val){
                elements.push(val.title)
            })
            $('#search').autocomplete({
                source:elements
            })
        })
    })
})
```

I think I have got this horribly wrong now but advice is appreciated as I am on a significant learning curve :-)

Comment: Have you setup your server to make it work without `index.php`?

Comment: yes I have. I am also using mssql and not MySQL If that makes a difference. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I gave up on the above and instead used a much simpler jquery autocomplete.

**Controller:**   [sales.php]

```
class Sales extends MY_Controller{

      function index(){
        $this->load->view('sales/new_order_details');
      } 

      function get_customers(){
        $this->load->model('Sales_model');
        if (isset($_GET['term'])){
          $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
          $this->Sales_model->get_customer($q);
        }
      }
}
```

**Model:**  [sales_model.php]

```
<?php
// (Array of Strings)
class Sales_model extends MY_Model{

  function get_customer($q){
    $this->db->select('CustomerName');
    $this->db->like('CustomerName', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('Customers');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
      foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
        $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['CustomerName'])); //build an array
      }
      echo json_encode($row_set); //format the array into json data
    }
  }
}
```

**View:**

```
<html>
   <head> 
      <link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css" media="screen" type="text/stylesheet" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>application/scripts/autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
   </head>
<body>
   <form>
      <label for="customer">Customer</label>
      <input type="text" id="customer" />
   </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Lastly, autocomplete.js:**

```
$(function(){
  $("#customer").autocomplete({
    source: "sales/get_customers"
  });
});
```

obviously you need the jquery files. can be found at http://jqueryui.com/, custom build and include the  autocomplete widget.

Works perfect and easily. Cheers.